# Wildfly 13 ejb stateless session bean not removed from pool

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ejb-3.1, stateless-session-bean

When load increases then stateless session beans count increases but later stateless beans are not removed from slsb-strict-max-pool when all are idle. Is there any setting to remove idle stateless bean ?
Same issue in wildly 21 also. See below, **pool-remove-count** is always 0.

standalone.xml

```
..........
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="60000" cache-ref="distributable" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="150" instance-acquisition-timeout="2" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="100" instance-acquisition-timeout="2" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
...................
```

```
sudo /opt/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c command="/deployment=Test-EAR.ear/subdeployment=Test.jar/subsystem=ejb3/stateless-session-bean=TestBean:read-resource(include-runtime=true)"
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "component-class-name" => "TestBean",
        "declared-roles" => [],
        "execution-time" => 237948636L,
        "invocations" => 67748L,
        "methods" => {"performRequest" => {
            "execution-time" => 237948636L,
            "invocations" => 67748L,
            "wait-time" => 4403L
        }},
        "peak-concurrent-invocations" => 150L,
        "pool-available-count" => 150,
        "pool-create-count" => 150,
        "pool-current-size" => 150,
        "pool-max-size" => 150,
        "pool-name" => "slsb-strict-max-pool",
        "pool-remove-count" => 0,
        "run-as-role" => undefined,
        "security-domain" => "other",
        "timers" => [],
        "wait-time" => 4403L,
        "service" => undefined
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove them? Typically they have quite low resource footprint. If you are struggling for memory, they are likely to be more effective ways to resolve

Comment: I think the pool-remove-count might actually reflect the count of "defective" beans. Try throwing an uncaught exception and see if it increases

Comment: @Will T  Thanks for reply. Actually i have Activemq connection variable on bean & on bean destroy I close this. So I wanted to remove them when bean are idle for long time. Is this wrong way to use bean? I will try your suggesion.

Comment: Are you using the JMS 2.0 API? Typically an EJB is only producer or consumer only for lifetime of a single invocation. I'm a little concerned from your wording that you might be to using the RemoteConnectionFacory or similar client api inside the container

Comment: Yes..Im using JMS 2.0 API. On bean, @PostConstruct method  I created activemq connection( like connection,  session, producer, consumer) using ConnectionFactory (resource-adapter setting in wildly where I have pools of connections as well as idle timeout). Anything wrong using such way ?

Comment: @Will T If you are struggling for memory, they are likely to be more effective ways to resolve --> Yes..Im getting memory issue & I suspect because of some peak a lot beans created with a lot activemq connection & since bean remains lifetime so occupying more memory. I exactly don't remember but in Glassfish/WebLogic we have option to destroy idle stateless beans but no such provision in wildly ??

Comment: As you are using v2.0 then your old field of the bean should be the JMSContext, see http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/jms-20-tutorial-on-wildfly-as

Comment: Thanks for reply. So here V2.0, no need to explicitly close activemq connection, right ?.  About stateless bean, it exist for lifetime in wildly ? No option to destroy idle beans ?

Comment: Correct, the connection lifecycle is managed for you.

Comment: Did you try throwing an exception to see if that counter increments?

I'm not aware of an option to kill off idle stateless bean instances

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227487/discussion-between-kunal-and-will-t).